# mongoose remove wrong document

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have 500 customers information, now I am adding one feature which checks for the customer ID and then remove it from the database but it removes wrong customer ID and for example it always remove the first customer from the collection here is my code..

```
router.post('/client', (req, res) => {
  customer.find({
    customerID: req.body.customerID
  }).then(customer => {
    if (customer.length) {
      const customerID = customer[0]._id;
      Customer.findByIdAndRemove(customerID).then(data => {
        if (data) {
          InvoicedCustomer.insertMany(data);
          return res.status(200).json(data);
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

so basically it finds ID in the body 12345 and then removes it from that Customer Collection and insert it into InvoicedCustomers, but problem is it does insert but it does not remove from Customer

Comment: in your second line should be `Customer` instead of `customer`

Comment: It didn't work either

Comment: console.log `customer` and `data` and post here the output

Comment: Your `Customer` model has both `customerID` and `_id` field?

Answer (score 1):

First, you no need to double query for the same thing 
here you trying to find the customer and if you get the customer then again you query to find the record which you double the cost.

> I think you can do it in one query like here

Note: I suppose here customerID is Unique

```
router.post('/client', (req, res) => {
    Customer.findOneAndRemove({
        customerID: req.body.customerID
    }).then(data => {
        if (data) {
            InvoicedCustomer.insertMany(data);
            return res.status(200).json(data);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        // handle error if any
        console.log(err)
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the reference ID? If so, you will have to create a middleware function to clean that part up.